# Saitama, Japan - Where's this purple beck with cherry blossoms?

Tags: japan, identify-this

[Reddit](https://redd.it/ai858a) asseverates it's in [Saitama](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Saitama,+Japan/@35.9683004,138.7150476,9z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x60192a8d477b01e9:0xfed91267aa80526c!8m2!3d35.9962513!4d139.4466005) Japan.

[image]

Comment: Beware that the white balance in that photo is pretty off kilter (see the woman's face and hands), so the scene will not be nearly as purple in real life.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like this is in Kawagoe, northwest of Tokyo. It is near the Kawagoe Hikawa shrine,  you can see the bridge from where the photo was likely taken in [Google Maps](https://www.google.com/maps/@35.9281009,139.4886164,3a,60y,298.61h,82.55t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1smrj0iuOKEdt7zL1LdnXSPA!2e0!7i16384!8i8192), which looks like a similar view as in your picture (you can see the dock a little ways up):[image]

Comment: Thanks!  have you been there? if not, how did you figure out the location?

Comment: I haven't been - I did a reverse image search which led to similar photos stating that it was on the Shingashi river in Kawagoe which narrowed it down. I looked that up in Google Maps and searched for "cherry blossoms" which led to that area. Actually here you can see a photo taken from the dock itself: https://goo.gl/maps/HUNsiEC1teUDWFtJA, much less purple in person